# Reorder / re-arrange multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, grouping

I have an array of data which contain buy and sell trades. I am trying to group the trades according to date, then consolidate the buys/sells within their own group. The input I have is as follows:

```
   Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => Buy
            [date] => 2011-02-14
            [instrument] => USD/CAD
            [units] => 2000.0
            [gbp_amount] => 12.4869
            [costs] => 0
            [duty] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => Sell
            [date] => 2011-02-14
            [instrument] => USD/CAD
            [units] => 2000.0
            [gbp_amount] => 14.62840335
            [costs] => 0
            [duty] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => Buy
            [date] => 2011-02-15
            [instrument] => USD/CAD
            [units] => 4000.0
            [gbp_amount] => 24.80064
            [costs] => 0
            [duty] => 0
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => Sell
            [date] => 2011-02-15
            [instrument] => USD/CAD
            [units] => 4000.0
            [gbp_amount] => 30.32498256
            [costs] => 0
            [duty] => 0
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => Buy
            [date] => 2011-02-21
            [instrument] => USD/CAD
            [units] => 4000.0
            [gbp_amount] => 24.63168
            [costs] => 0
            [duty] => 0
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => Sell
            [date] => 2011-02-21
            [instrument] => USD/CAD
            [units] => 4000.0
            [gbp_amount] => 26.633004
            [costs] => 0
            [duty] => 0
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => Buy
            [date] => 2011-02-21
            [instrument] => USD/CAD
            [units] => 4000.0
            [gbp_amount] => 24.63168
            [costs] => 0
            [duty] => 0
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => Sell
            [date] => 2011-02-22
            [instrument] => USD/CAD
            [units] => 4000.0
            [gbp_amount] => 27.0270324
            [costs] => 0
            [duty] => 0
        )

    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => Buy
            [date] => 2011-02-21
            [instrument] => USD/CAD
            [units] => 2000.0
            [gbp_amount] => 12.31584
            [costs] => 0
            [duty] => 0
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => Sell
            [date] => 2011-02-22
            [instrument] => USD/CAD
            [units] => 2000.0
            [gbp_amount] => 13.88811768
            [costs] => 0
            [duty] => 0
        )

    [10] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => Buy
            [date] => 2011-04-21
            [instrument] => USD/CAD
            [units] => 1000.0
            [gbp_amount] => 12.09882
            [costs] => 0
            [duty] => 0
        )

    [11] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => Sell
            [date] => 2011-04-22
            [instrument] => USD/CAD
            [units] => 1000.0
            [gbp_amount] => 13.87129713
            [costs] => 0
            [duty] => 0
        )

    [12] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => Buy
            [date] => 2012-02-01
            [instrument] => USD/CAD
            [units] => 13.5
            [gbp_amount] => 0.8517069
            [costs] => 0
            [duty] => 0
        )

    [13] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => Sell
            [date] => 2012-02-01
            [instrument] => USD/CAD
            [units] => 13.5
            [gbp_amount] => 0.8517069
            [costs] => 0
            [duty] => 0
        )

    [14] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => Buy
            [date] => 2012-02-01
            [instrument] => USD/CAD
            [units] => 27.0
            [gbp_amount] => 0.68136552
            [costs] => 0
            [duty] => 0
        )

    [15] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => Sell
            [date] => 2012-02-01
            [instrument] => USD/CAD
            [units] => 27.0
            [gbp_amount] => 0.68136552
            [costs] => 0
            [duty] => 0
        )

    [16] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => Buy
            [date] => 2012-02-01
            [instrument] => USD/CAD
            [units] => 13.5
            [gbp_amount] => 0.34068276
            [costs] => 0
            [duty] => 0
        )

    [17] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => Sell
            [date] => 2012-02-01
            [instrument] => USD/CAD
            [units] => 13.5
            [gbp_amount] => 0.34068276
            [costs] => 0
            [duty] => 0
        )

    [18] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => Buy
            [date] => 2012-02-01
            [instrument] => USD/CAD
            [units] => 13.5
            [gbp_amount] => 0.34068276
            [costs] => 0
            [duty] => 0
        )

    [19] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => Sell
            [date] => 2012-02-01
            [instrument] => USD/CAD
            [units] => 13.5
            [gbp_amount] => 0.34068276
            [costs] => 0
            [duty] => 0
        )

)
```

The output I am looking to achieve is this :

```
    Array
(
    [2011-02-14] => stdClass Object
            [Buy] => Array
                [0] = Array
                    (
                        [instrument] => USD/CAD
                        [units] => 2000.0
                        [gbp_amount] => 12.4869
                        [costs] => 0
                        [duty] => 0
                    )

            [Sell] => Array
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [instrument] => USD/CAD
                        [units] => 2000.0
                        [gbp_amount] => 14.62840335
                        [costs] => 0
                        [duty] => 0
                    )

    [2011-02-15] => stdClass Object
            [Buy] => Array
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [instrument] => USD/CAD
                        [units] => 4000.0
                        [gbp_amount] => 24.80064
                        [costs] => 0
                        [duty] => 0
                    )

            [Sell] => Array
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [instrument] => USD/CAD
                        [units] => 4000.0
                        [gbp_amount] => 30.32498256
                        [costs] => 0
                        [duty] => 0
                    )

    [2011-02-21] => stdClass Object
            [Buy] => Array
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [instrument] => USD/CAD
                        [units] => 4000.0
                        [gbp_amount] => 24.63168
                        [costs] => 0
                        [duty] => 0
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [instrument] => USD/CAD
                        [units] => 4000.0
                        [gbp_amount] => 24.63168
                        [costs] => 0
                        [duty] => 0
                    )

            [Sell] => Array
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [instrument] => USD/CAD
                        [units] => 4000.0
                        [gbp_amount] => 26.633004
                        [costs] => 0
                        [duty] => 0
                    )

    [2011-02-22] => stdClass Object
            [Buy] => Array
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [instrument] => USD/CAD
                        [units] => 2000.0
                        [gbp_amount] => 12.31584
                        [costs] => 0
                        [duty] => 0
                    )

            [Sell] => Array
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [instrument] => USD/CAD
                        [units] => 4000.0
                        [gbp_amount] => 27.0270324
                        [costs] => 0
                        [duty] => 0
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [instrument] => USD/CAD
                        [units] => 2000.0
                        [gbp_amount] => 13.88811768
                        [costs] => 0
                        [duty] => 0
                    )

    [2011-04-21] => stdClass Object
            [Buy] => Array
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [instrument] => USD/CAD
                        [units] => 1000.0
                        [gbp_amount] => 12.09882
                        [costs] => 0
                        [duty] => 0
                    )

    [2011-04-22] => stdClass Object
            [Sell] => Array
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [instrument] => USD/CAD
                        [units] => 1000.0
                        [gbp_amount] => 13.87129713
                        [costs] => 0
                        [duty] => 0
                    )

    [2012-02-01] => stdClass Object
            [Buy] => Array
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [instrument] => USD/CAD
                        [units] => 13.5
                        [gbp_amount] => 0.8517069
                        [costs] => 0
                        [duty] => 0
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [instrument] => USD/CAD
                        [units] => 27.0
                        [gbp_amount] => 0.68136552
                        [costs] => 0
                        [duty] => 0
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [instrument] => USD/CAD
                        [units] => 13.5
                        [gbp_amount] => 0.34068276
                        [costs] => 0
                        [duty] => 0
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [instrument] => USD/CAD
                        [units] => 13.5
                        [gbp_amount] => 0.34068276
                        [costs] => 0
                        [duty] => 0
                    )

            [Sell] => Array
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [instrument] => USD/CAD
                        [units] => 13.5
                        [gbp_amount] => 0.8517069
                        [costs] => 0
                        [duty] => 0
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [instrument] => USD/CAD
                        [units] => 27.0
                        [gbp_amount] => 0.68136552
                        [costs] => 0
                        [duty] => 0
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [instrument] => USD/CAD
                        [units] => 13.5
                        [gbp_amount] => 0.34068276
                        [costs] => 0
                        [duty] => 0
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [instrument] => USD/CAD
                        [units] => 13.5
                        [gbp_amount] => 0.34068276
                        [costs] => 0
                        [duty] => 0
                    )

)
```

I've tried using foreach loops to re-arrange the array but i'm having little success other than getting the trades to list by date, but i'm unable to then list these according to buy/sells. Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$res = array();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $tmp = (array)$item;
    unset($tmp['date'], $tmp['action']);
    $res[$item->date][$item->action][] = $tmp;
}
print_r($res);
```

It casts each object into an array, uses (and then removes) the date and action fields as the keys for the resulting array and voila :)